# Defaults used by Spring boot - spring-boot-starter-parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am just starting with Spring boot and came to know that with Spring boot, it gives the "defaults" (Convention over configuration) so that almost 80% dependencies are met.

```
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Consider the above version of `spring-boot-starter-parent` , how can I know what the defaults spring boot is going to propose for my project? Is there a way to find what defaults it is going to choose?

Can anyone help me understand it please?

Comment: Defaults for what?  All the start parent does is bring in all the Maven dependencies that your version of Spring Boot demands.

Comment: Does it define what jar versions to be used, including project jars (custom code jars)

Comment: No, you add what you need in addition to what Spring Boot wants.  They don't know your requirements.  You can open the parent pom and see what they bring in.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot has what is called Starters.  A starter is a set of convenient dependencies that you can include in your project to help to achieve something.

The boot starter includes auto-configuration support, logging and YAML.

There are starters for security, data (jpa), mongodb, etc..

You can take a look here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-starter

Answer (score 0):

You could use two built-in maven goals to get information about dependencies and things inherited in your pom:

- [`mvn dependency:tree`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) to display the dependency tree.
- [`mvn help:effective-pom`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) to display  the effective POM as an XML for the build.

The first focuses on dependencies (and its origins) which the second focuses on the resulted pom.xml after dependencies (and profile) resolution.

Additionally, Spring Boot relies on [some common properties with sometimes default values](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

---

Note that these maven goals can be used by specifying the artifact to analyse.
For example to get the effective pom of the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE` dependency, run it :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:effective-pom -Dartifact=org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.0.RELEASE
```

It will output something like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../../spring-boot-dependencies</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Spring Boot Starter Parent</name>
  <description>Parent pom providing dependency and plugin management for applications
        built with Maven</description>
  <url>https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#/spring-boot-starter-parent</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Pivotal</name>
      <email>info@pivotal.io</email>
      <organization>Pivotal Software, Inc.</organization>
      <organizationUrl>http://www.spring.io</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <url>https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/spring-boot-starter-parent</url>
  </scm>
  <properties>
    <activemq.version>5.15.3</activemq.version>
    <antlr2.version>2.7.7</antlr2.version>
    <appengine-sdk.version>1.9.62</appengine-sdk.version>
 <!--  and so for -->
```

Similarly you could output the dependency tree only for some artifacts/groups.
To filter only artifacts/groups that contains the "hibernate" in their naming you could do that :

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=*hibernate*
```

that could output the following if your pom depends on spring-boot-starter-data-jpa :

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.2.14.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.7.Final:compile
```